# Color change for mat select place holder with out required field validation

Tags: angular

[image: ![]

when page loads,text color for all controls(city,state..) is white in Image 1 and I need to change text color to red for all controls on page load which should look like below image. [image: ][1]]

FromName : SectionAForm
Below Country* need to be in red color on page load

```
<mat-form-field> 
<mat-select placeholder="County*" formControlName="aA_COUNTY_CODE"
aria-label="County"> <mat-option *ngFor="let county of counties" 
[value]="county.countY_CODE"> {{ county.countY_NAME }} 
</mat-option> </mat-select> 
<mat-error *ngIf="sectionAForm.get('aA_COUNTY_CODE').errors?.required">County 
Required</mat-error> 
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Edit your post to make it clear, and define your issue.

Comment: @Emilien edited my posted.please review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use markAsTouched() on a formControl, in ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.yourFormControl.markAsTouched();
}
```

If your formControl has a required Validator, the input will be colored red.
Hope it will help you.

EDIT:

In your case, placing

```
this.sectionAForm.get('aA_COUNTY_CODE').markAsTouched()
```

Or

```
this.sectionAForm.get('aA_COUNTY_CODE').markAsDirty()
```

In ngOnInit(), should work.

Comment: Below is code for one of the control, it's do not have required Validator instead it has invalid. <mat-error *ngIf="sectionAForm.get('aA_COUNTY_CODE').errors?.required">County Required</mat-error>

Comment: Are you using a formGroup ? if yes, can you put it on your post ?

Comment: <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select placeholder="County*" formControlName="aA_COUNTY_CODE" aria-label="County">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let county of counties" [value]="county.countY_CODE">
                      {{ county.countY_NAME }}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="sectionAForm.get('aA_COUNTY_CODE').errors?.required">County Required</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

Comment: i guess sectionAFom is a formGroup, can you put his declaration in your original post ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206469/discussion-between-user2271011-and-soukyone).